# How to find contour of an image with missing part?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Grocery bill:

[image: a grocery bill]

As some of the top and bottom part of the image is missing the biggest contour i.e. the main bill cannot be cropped. The code works well in case of a complete bill image but fails to handle a missing-vertex image.

Code:

```py
imgContours = img.copy() # COPY ORIGNAL IMAGE
imgBigContour = img.copy() # COPY ORIGNAL IMAGE
_, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(imgThreshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) # FIND ALL CONTOURS
cv2.drawContours(imgContours, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 10) # DRAW ALL DETECTED CONTOURS

# FIND THE BIGGEST COUNTOUR
biggest, maxArea = utlis.biggestContour(contours) # FIND THE BIGGEST CONTOUR
if biggest.size != 0:
    biggest=utlis.reorder(biggest)
    cv2.drawContours(imgBigContour, biggest, -1, (0, 255, 0), 20) # DRAW THE BIGGEST CONTOUR
    imgBigContour = utlis.drawRectangle(imgBigContour,biggest,2)
    pts1 = np.float32(biggest) # PREPARE POINTS FOR WARP
    pts2 = np.float32([[0, 0],[widthImg, 0], [0, heightImg],[widthImg, heightImg]]) # PREPARE POINTS FOR WARP
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
    imgWarpColored = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (widthImg, heightImg))
```

Comment: add a 1px black border all around the image, see `copyMakeBorder`

Comment: this situation can't be solved easily. you would have to analyze the text on the receipt to figure out the approximate perspective of the photo.

Comment: @Miki your answer was really helpfull. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by one of the person in comments i.e. use `cv2.copyMakeBorder()` it worked. So the proper syntax with respect to the above code of reference will be:

```
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

actually what it does is that it adds a black border of 10 pixels on each side. And further when we use `cv2.findContour()` it actually detects the largest one(including the previous small ones) which wasn't counted earlier.